# Error from cross domain jQuery.ajax request, but works in old version

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/auth",
    type: "POST",
    data: "username=example&password=mypasswd",
    success: function(returned) {
        // do stuff
    },
    error: function(returned) {
        console.log(returned);
    }
});
```

It works fine with jQuery 1.3.2 for which I wrote it a while ago, but after updating to 1.7.1 today, it returns this:

```
Object { readyState=0, status=0, statusText="error"}
```

I could not get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the way to look at this is... how did it work in in 1.3.2? The browser rejects cross-domain ajax requests.

Comment: I believe you need to use jsonp for cross domain requests.

Comment: Here's a fiddle demonstrating that cross-domain ajax requests did not work in 1.3.2 http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/bpb5B/

Comment: All I can tell you is that right now the code I posted definitely works for me using jQuery 1.3.2. I know it sounds impossible, it took me a whole afternoon to realize this, but I narrowed it down to the point where only this is left from my code, and I'm sure it works in 1.3.2. I'm sorry, but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in you code that you are telling the jQuery AJAX function that it is doing a cross-domain call. Try adding `dataType : 'jsonp'` as one of the options in your `$.ajax()` call:

```
$.ajax({
    url      : "http://example.com/auth",
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    type     : "POST",
    data     : "username=example&password=mypasswd",
    success  : function(returned) {
        // do stuff
    },
    error    : function(returned) {
        console.log(returned);
    }
});
```

> Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra "?callback=?" to the
>   end of your URL to specify the callback. Disables caching by appending
>   a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache
>   option is set to true.

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/*

Comment: `jsonp` can't be type `POST` though. That can't be how it was working in `1.3.2` unless his server-side code is written to accept `GET` params instead of `POST`. In jQuery 1.3.2, if you didn't set that you were requesting jsonp, it would fail (according to a few small test cases i wrote).

Answer (score 0):

This is because Cross-origin policy. you need to configure your server to accept an option call before.

More details can be found at:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: please give more details about how to implement a cross domain request, or you will just mentioning what was already said in comments